# Move logic from Controller to Service class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I'm working on a simple login page which works already, but I wanna experiment with Service classes and how they work.

How would I be able to properly move my logic from my controller to a service class, and call that service class in my controller?

**AuthController:**

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard')
                    ->withSuccess('You have successfully logged in');
    }

    return redirect("login")
    ->withSuccess('Oops! You have entered invalid credentials'); // MIGHT CHANGE TO withSuccess
}
```

I've made a **UserService.php** file under **App\Services**

I've tried pasting the function into my Service class, then calling it in the controller with

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    (new UserService())->postLogin($request->validated());
}
```

Comment: It's good that you're refactoring. Does it work? If not, what result are you seeing? Also, are you using a framework of some sort? If you're using Symfony, for example, you'll want to google `symfony dependency injection` for a good how-to. If you're not using a framework, there are also good standalone DI containers out there, though I haven't used any.

Comment: @MayorofthePlattenbaus They're using Laravel 9, according to their tags

Comment: What happens when you try? It looks like you moved the validation to the UserService, so you won't be able to pass `$request->validated()` from your controller, since there's no validation there. You'll also need to return the response in your controller that you got from the Service class

Comment: @aynber When calling it using `(new UserService())->postLogin($request->validated());` I'm indeed getting an error since I can't pass it: `Method Illuminate\Http\Request::validated does not exist.` How would I fix this? And what do I have to return (noobie questions, I'm new haha)

Comment: If the new `postLogin` is expecting a request, especially if it's going to validate there, then pass in the `$request`. And just add `return` in front of the statement in your controller, so it will return whatever the service container returns